# LList::LList() referenced from main.o - XCode error message

Tags: c++, xcode, hyperlink, reference

I am trying to implement a singly linked list class in C++. I have no idea if my content is organized in each file correctly. I hace LList.h, LList.cpp and test.cpp. The error I think has somethingt to do with my default constructor.I keep getting 3 compiler errors on my Mac in XCode. Here is my Code

```
// LList.h:

#ifndef LList_LList_h
#define LList_LList_h


struct Node {
    char info;
    Node *next;
};

class LList {

private:

    Node *head;

    Node *cons(char ch, Node *p);

    Node *deleteAll(char ch, Node *p);

    Node * insert(char ch, Node *p);

public:

    LList();
    ~LList();
    LList(LList &list);

    bool isEmpty() const;

    void print() const;

};

#endif
```

---

```
// LList.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "LList.h"
#ifndef LList_LList_h
#define LList_LList_h

LList::LList() :list(nullptr) {
    // no body

}

Node LList::cons(char ch, Node *p) {
        Node *q = new Node;
        q->info = ch;
        q->next = p;
        return q;
    }

Node *LList::deleteAll(char ch, Node *p) {
        if (p == nullptr || ch < p->info) {
            return p;
        }
        if (ch == p->info) {
            Node *discard = p;
            p = p->next;
            delete discard;
            return deleteAll(ch, p->next);
        } else {
            return deleteAll(ch, p->next);
        }
    }

Node *LList::insert(char ch, Node *p) {
        if (p == nullptr || ch <= p->info) {
            return cons(ch,p);
        }
        Node *q = p;
        Node *r = q->next;

        while (r != nullptr && ch > r->info) {
            q=r;
            r=r->next;
    }
        q->next = cons(ch,p);
        return p;
    }


bool LList::isEmpty() const{
        return (head == nullptr);
    }

void LList::print (Node *p) {

        while (p != nullptr) {
            std::cout << p->info << " ";
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
#endif
_______________
```

---

```
//test.cpp 


#include "LList.h"

int main() {
    LList list;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Please help!!
My errors say:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "LList::LList()", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "LList::~LList()", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: One problem is: You define destructor but you don't implement it. But I cannot answer to everything because I suspect that the header and body files are not synchronized: you define the constructor (so should not be undefined symbol at link time) but your constructor sets `list` to `nullptr`, but `list` is nowhere to be found in the header file... Please post the exact code you are using.

Comment: I tried changing the variable name to 'list' and then i changed it to 'head', so i forgot to change it back . Either way, it still doesnt work even if i put:

LList::LList():{
  
}

or 

LList::LList(): head(nullptr){
  
}

or 

LList::LList(): head->next(nullptr){
  
}

Comment: TL;DR remove the include guards from your `.cpp` file. Voting to close as trivial error, unlikely to help future readers etc.